# Why am I not able to use this script in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, php

I'm not able to use this code in php.. I'm using dreamweaver

```
{
<SCRIPT language = "JavaScript">

var counter = 0;

// call Update function in 2 seconds after first load
ID = window . setTimeout("Update();", 2000);

function Update() {
    counter++;
    window.status = "The counter is now at " + counter;
    document.form1.input1.value = "The counter is now at " + counter;

    // set another timeout for the next count   
    ID = window . setTimeout("Update();", 2000);
}

</SCRIPT>
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use it in PHP? Please elaborate on your problem. This is not Twitter, you have more than 140 characters to describe the issue.

Comment: How "i'm not able to" ? What is the problem ? Is there an error ?

Comment: Are you literally in a PHP block as you try to output this?

Comment: no there is no error message but counter stick at 0 only that is not increment after 2 sec.

Comment: i just want to print counter after every 2 sec. and below this there is my php code for database connection and etc. and html form also..i need to print counter that's it.please give any alternative or modification in this code.my file extension is .php

Answer (score 1):

You are not outputting the script: The page needs to have HTML content in which to execute JavaScript (by the browser).
[Echo](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp) your script and go from there.

```
<?php
{
echo'<SCRIPT language = "JavaScript">

var counter = 0;

// call Update function in 2 seconds after first load
ID = window . setTimeout("Update();", 2000);

function Update() {
    counter++;
    window.status = "The counter is now at " + counter;
    document.form1.input1.value = "The counter is now at " + counter;

    // set another timeout for the next count   
    ID = window . setTimeout("Update();", 2000);
}

</SCRIPT>';
} ?>
```

Comment: If what the OP has would literally be inside a PHP file, it would output just fine. See http://codepad.org/WTC9RPP3

Comment: yes, I assumed he was inside a PHP block though based on the title and tags... That was a bit hasty, I admit